# Store Result of While Loop in Array and Assign a session to the Array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have a search query that will fetch a record in my database

code:

```
while($pid_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_pid_check))  
{ 
echo $pid_row['pid_code']; 
}
```

I want all the result in the while loop to be stored in an array ang assign a session variable for the array...

How can I achieve it... Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
$results = array();
while($pid_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_pid_check))  
{ 
array_push($results,$pid_row['pid_code']); 
}

$_SESSION['resultsarr']=$results;
```

Don't forget to add `session_start();` at the begining of your PHP code.

You can now print your results from the session variable like

```
print_r($_SESSION['resultsarr']);
```

Answer (score 2):

To fetch all the result without using while loop.

```
session_start();
$results = array();
$pid_row=sqlsrv_fetch_all($stmt_pid_check);
array_push($results,$pid_row);
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
session_start();
$results = array();
while($pid_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_pid_check))  
{ 
$results[] = $pid_row['pid_code']; 
}

$_SESSION['resultsarr'] = $results;
```